# How malloc allocates space while inserting values to a binary search tree?

Tags: c, malloc, binary-search-tree, function-pointers, tree-traversal

bellow there is a simple code for a binary search tree. It has 2 cases, the first one inserts values to the tree and the second one finds the preorder traversal of the tree.

My question has to do with the malloc function. In the first case we have this `ptr = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));` and lets say that the value that we want to insert is 50. I can see while debugging that ptr=50 and I can't understand how `(struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node))` gives this result.

Also when we have `struct node *ptr, *nodeptr, *parentptr` as pointing variables to struct node inside the function and after that we have for example `parentptr=NULL;` this `parentptr` refers to the pointer `*parentptr` or its just a variable.

```
struct node
{
  int data;
  struct node* left;
  struct node* right;
};

struct node* tree;
struct node*
insert(struct node*, int);
void
preorder(struct node*);
int
main()
{
  int option, val;
  struct node* ptr;
  tree = NULL;
  do {
    printf("\n ******MAIN MENU******* \n");
    printf("\n 1. Insert an element");
    printf("\n 2. Preorder Traversal");
    printf("\n 3. Exit");
    printf("\n\n Enter your option : ");
    scanf("%d", &option);

    switch (option) {
      case 1:
        printf("\n Enter the value of the new node : ");
        scanf("%d", &val);
        tree = insert(tree, val);
        break;

      case 2:
        printf("\n The elements of the tree are : \n");
        preorder(tree);
        break;
    }
  } while (option != 3);
  getch();
  return 0;
}

struct node*
insert(struct node* tree, int val)
{
  struct node *ptr, *nodeptr, *parentptr;

  ptr = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
  ptr->data = val;
  ptr->left = NULL;
  ptr->right = NULL;

  if (tree == NULL) {
    tree = ptr;
    tree->left = NULL;
    tree->right = NULL;
  } else {
    nodeptr = tree;
    parentptr = NULL;
    while (nodeptr != NULL) {
      parentptr = nodeptr;
      if (val < nodeptr->data)
        nodeptr = nodeptr->left;
      else
        nodeptr = nodeptr->right;
    }
    if (val < parentptr->data)
      parentptr->left = ptr;
    else
      parentptr->right = ptr;
  }
  return tree;
}

void
preorder(struct node* tree)
{
  if (tree != NULL) {
    printf("%d\t", tree->data);
    preorder(tree->left);
    preorder(tree->right);
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you show us debugger output that displays `ptr` as 50?

Comment: @dbush my bad sorry, ptr has a strange value while debugging. I am saying that ptr is equal to 50 because for example, when I set the value to 50 and I want to insert it to the tree. Then the function is called and says that "ptr = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));" and some lines bellow we have "tree=ptr;". This is the location that I can see that tree gets 50 so that means that tree is 50.

Comment: By "strange value", do you mean that it is an address?  The assignment `ptr->data = val` is assigning the value of 50.  The malloc just allocates space so that `ptr->data` is a valid memory location.

Comment: After the `malloc` call `ptr->data = val` sets the `data` member of that node to 50, and if `tree` is NULL then `tree` is set to `ptr`, so `tree->val` will be 50.

Comment: @dbush appreciate your help thank you, understood.

Comment: Using a pointer-to-pointer will simplify the insert function to about ten lines.

Comment: BTW: is this the *complete* code? Did you `#include <stdlib.h>` ?

Comment: @wildplasser yes, I just didn't type it here.